# Loading more than one custom cell from Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This works perfect if I return just 1 row of cells.
But if I put more than 1 I get the error message: "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"

I have made a xib file that has one table cell with a unique design and I just want to use that over and over only changing some labels.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 2;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

        SectionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {


            NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ButtonCell" owner:self options:nil];

cell = [[SectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

            cell = (SectionCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }


        cell.backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;

        cell.name.text=@"Cell Test";


        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return cell;
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return YES;
    }
    */


    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 78;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this code snipped:

```
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[SectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
```

and remove your NSBundle logic as it is no longer necessary since you are instantiating the cell object yourself.

Example:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
        SectionCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
            cell = [[[SectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ] autorelease];

        cell.backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
        cell.name.text=@"Cell Test";
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return cell;
    }
```

Tip:

It isn't necessary to continuously set your tableview backgrounds the way you do.  You can set it when your object is first loaded.

Comment: Since he's loading the cell from the xib named "ButtonCell", I think he should just use : cell = (SectionCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0]; instead of instantiating the cell object .. right?

Comment: Still the same error. It's so odd since there isn't any other code in the project.  It's like there is something missing when I return a 2 instead of a 1 for "- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section"

Comment: @DhruvGoel He could rely on NSBundle to instantiate it for him or he can instantiate it himself.  I think it is best to take the NSBundle out of the equation in order to better troubleshoot his issue.

Comment: @jdross You shouldn't be getting that error in my example since you are no longer working with an NSArray.  Did your error change?

Comment: It does, but I have the tableview to be set as static, does that cause the problem?

Comment: I changed it to dynamic and it works, but I can no longer use the custom table cell

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using :

```
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

use:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ButtonCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (SectionCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

}
```

Because your nib probably has only one object i.e your custom table view cell.

PS: Assuming you have a xib named "ButtonCell" having a single custom view with its custom class set to "SectionCell"

Comment: Your correct about the xib name and having a single custom view and set to the class section cell.  However, I still seem to be getting the same error when I made the code change

Comment: are you using objectAtIndex:0 and getting that error? Weird. Can you put a NSLog statement just after you load the nib using : NSLog(@"nib array : %@", nib);

Comment: I did set it to use objectAtIndex:0.   Here's the log, it's generated twice since I have it to return 2 rows.                                2013-02-06 13:55:25.697 Campmeeting2[6022:c07] nib array : (
    "<SectionCell: 0x84318b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 62); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x84319e0>>"
)
2013-02-06 13:55:25.701 Campmeeting2[6022:c07] nib array : (
    "<SectionCell: 0x777d3e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 62); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x777d510>>"
)

Comment: To expand on Dhruv's comment, the return value of the `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method will return only the top-level objects in the nib file.  So, if your cell object is added to something else's control hierarchy, then you need to account for that.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the comment.  It isn't added to anything else hierarchy.  The odd thing is if I have it return just 1 row it works perfectly

Comment: Then its likely you didn't do what Dhruv suggested.  Sounds like you are still using `indexPath.row`.  Please edit your post to reflect your most recent changes and let us take another look-see.  Thanks.

Comment: The error "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]" made sense when you were using [nib objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], because when indexPath.row was equal to 1, it threw an error because nib array has only a single object (as you can see in the logs). If you're still getting the same error, the problem is probably not in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but maybe somewhere else

Comment: This is the latest code:   cell = [[SectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ButtonCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (SectionCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        
        NSLog(@"nib array : %d", nib.count);

Comment: Update your original post so we can get all the juicy syntax highlighting and formatting.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original.  Sorry for the mess, it didn't like some of the formatting

Comment: And remember if I change the 2 to a 1 for rows returned, it works

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had to not use static for the table view and use dynamic prototype.  The only downside is I couldn't use the custom xib cell and had to modify the default cell to look  as close as possible to my static cell.